# Javascript Scope of a variable from a script to another

Tags: javascript, scope

I cannot figure how to solve this problem, I searched how to share a global variable but in my code I really can't implement it the ways I found it. I have the function `createBoard()` written in the ***1st*** script : let's name it `create.js`. Then in the ***2nd*** script : `customize.js` I have this function that for every `<a> element` found in a page, it assigns this function if the element is being clicked:

```
2nd script (customize.js)
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      var clickedLink = link.id;
      alert(clickedLink); // ----> Output == Actual string of the clicked link id.
      createBoard(clickedLink); 
    });
  });
```

The `alert(clickedLink)` actually displays the correct id that is being clicked upon an `<a>` . So if I click an `<a>` the function `createBoard()` works and gets called correctly, but if I try to add a `console.log(parameter)` to display the content of the parameter passed from `customize.js` to `create.js` it returns undefined and I must have the parameter in order to create the correct board. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
1st script (create.js)
createBoard(parameter){
   console.log(parameter) // ----> Output == "undefined"
}
```

Comment: Probably should not use a link for action like that. A button would be more appropriate.
I'm suspecting you're not getting anything into your `createBoard` function because your browser will follow the link's href.

Comment: The code you've shared seems fine. Are you sure you're calling the right function?

Comment: Are you calling **createBoard** somewhere else in your code and you are seeing there? I would look for every reference to **createBoard**.

Comment: I just found out that I was calling the function without parameters on a `<body onload=“createBoard()”></body>` so I suppose that the undefined refers to the non existent parameter. I will try to find another solution to the problem. Thank you for the help :)